# Every tournament is diconnected or can be made into one by the reorientation of just one arc

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that every tournament $T$ is diconnected or can be made into one by
>   the reorientation of just one arc of $T$

I really don't know what to do, I don't even have a clue of why is this true! I mean, it's just **one** arc! I got this far:

Let $T$ be a tournament that is not diconnected, then there are two vertex $u,v$ such that $u$ is not reachable from $v$. Since the underlying graph is complete, we have a path from $u$ to $v$. In the tournament, this path must have an arc (**or maybe several**!) that makes $u$ is not reachable from $v$. That is the problem, that I may have a lot of problems!

Comment: If $u$ ans $v$ have $n$ disjoints connecting paths in a graph then at least $n$ edges have to be broken to disconnect them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem

Comment: What makes a tournament "diconnected"? 2 internally-disjoint directed paths between any two vertices?

Comment: @Hermine: every tournament contains a Hamilton path (which follows by the theorem of Gallai & Milgram, by the way). What happens if we reorient (if necessary) the edge connecting the two end vertices of this  Hamilton path so that it becomes a Hamilton cycle? Think about it: this could be your anser and solution.

Comment: @Casteels: my interpretation of "diconnected" is "strongly connected".

Comment: @Casteels a tournament is diconnected if for any two vertices, one is reachable from the other, i.e, there is a directed path joining them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

First prove that every tournament has a Hamiltonian path (this is easy by induction: you can "squeeze in" the new vertex).

If this Hamiltonian path is a cycle we are done.

Otherwise revert the arc between its endpoints.

Comment: This doesn't work for a tournament of order $2$. But then nothing does.

Comment: You are right, order 2 must be excluded from the problem.